# replace number with string inside javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to replace a numeric value in a javascript array with a string?

for example:

```
var a=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I need to replace #3 with apple.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3):

Use `.indexOf(3)` to find where 3 is in the array, and then just do `a[index] = "apple";` to replace the value. I created a snipped for you below.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var index = a.indexOf(3);

console.log("Before: " + a);
a[index] = "apple";
console.log("After: " + a);
```

Comment: i was  asked  this question on job  interview and i gave exactly same answer. a[2] =' apple'. it was marked as wrong:(.

Comment: @marb there is another solution by manonthemat. I believe that couldve been why it was wrong

Answer (score 3):

Aniket G's solution works, but only replaces the first occurrence of a value.

```js
// arr is the array we're acting on
// n is the value we want to replace
// str is the string that we want n replaced with
function replaceNumWithStringInArray(arr, n, str) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] === n) {
      // we found a match, replace the former value (n) with a string (str)
      arr[i] = str;
    }
  }
  // we don't have to return anything here, because it modifies the array in place
}

var a = [1,2,3,4,5,3]; // added another 3 to illustrate that it replaces all occurences of n
console.log('before', a);
replaceNumWithStringInArray(a, 3, 'apple');
console.log('after', a);
```

Comment: I completely forgot about that. Thanks for correcting me!

Comment: why typeof ("" + 1 + 0) is a string but typeof ("" - 1 + 0) is a number?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course it's possible! I suggest you read some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) on javascript arrays to see just how powerful they are.

Basically, javascript arrays are high-level list objects that can be made up of many different data-types. If you would have actually *tried* what you were curious about before asking about it here, you would have found it to be quite simple.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
a[2] = "apple";
```

Replaces the third element of array `a` with `"apple"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over your array and check for the given value. Especially useful if the value occurs multiple times:

```
function stringifyValue(array, valueToStringify) {
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] === valueToStringify){
      array[i] = '' + array[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Or if you want to update a value at the given index:

```
const indexWithValue = 3;
array[indexWithValue] = '' + array[indexWithValue];
```